# How to develop a custom input method on IOS platform

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I want to develop a custom input method on iOS platform.

From now on, Apple doesn't provide any input method API of this field.

I know that if we want to install a new input method, we need to jb first and install the new method from Cydia

So, can anybody help me to find the API about how to develop a new input method for iOS.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What is a "customer input method"?

Comment: which means i can add a new keyboard to text some other characters

Comment: Oh _custom_ input method, not custom _er_! I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to jailbreak to use a custom keyboard in your app. You can create your own keyboard view and set it as the `.inputView` of your text field.

To replace the keyboard across the whole device, you would need to jailbreak, but I don't know what you'd need to do next, so apologies if that is your question.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i want to get the character of iOS system, like chinese character, so that i can show the chinese character on the screen.